# System-wide redirect traffic to local proxy server using iptables

Tags: iptables, proxy

The code used in my example is taken from a `REDSOCKS` tutorial but it doesn't do the job for me. I'm trying to redirect all my tcp traffic through a local proxy server.

```
#!/bin/bash

CHAIN="MYCHAIN"
PROTO="tcp"

iptables -t nat -N ${CHAIN}

# Ignore LANs and some other reserved addresses.
iptables -t nat -A ${CHAIN} -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A ${CHAIN} -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A ${CHAIN} -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A ${CHAIN} -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A ${CHAIN} -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A ${CHAIN} -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A ${CHAIN} -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A ${CHAIN} -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

# Anything else should be redirected to port 12345
iptables -t nat -A ${CHAIN} -p ${PROTO} -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
iptables -A INPUT -p ${PROTO} -j ${CHAIN}
```

I receive this error when executing the script: `iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load target 'MYCHAIN':No such file or directory`.

I think I'm missing a rule but I can't figure out which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would have to create `MYCHAIN` before,

hint:

try **TPROXY** target (in **PREROUTING** / **mangle**  ).

( only valid in the mangle table, in the PREROUTING chain and user-defined chains which are only called from this chain) .

they have a good example :

#### `iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 50080`

#### from the manual:

It redirects the packet to a local socket without changing the packet header in any way. It can also change the mark value which can then be used in advanced routing rules. It takes three options:

- `--on-port port`

  This specifies a destination port to use. It is a required option, 0 means the new destination port is the same as the original. This is only valid if the rule also specifies -p tcp or -p udp.
- `--on-ip address`

  This specifies a destination address to use. By default the address is the IP address of the incoming interface. This is only valid if the rule also specifies -p tcp or -p udp.
- `--tproxy-mark value[/mask]`

  Marks packets with the given value/mask. The fwmark value set here can be used by advanced routing. (Required for transparent proxying to work: otherwise these packets will get forwarded, which is probably not what you want.)

references :

[tproxy documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt)

[netfilter man](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating `MYCHAIN` in the `nat` table. Last command in your example is inserting rule to `filter` table `INPUT` chain, with a jump target of `MYCHAIN` in `filter` table.

Since no such chain existsm you get the error message.